# Why does NumPy.exp show a different result than exp in C

Tags: python, c, numpy, exponent

I am converting some Python code to C code.

Below Python NumPy exp on complex number outputs `(6.12323399574e-17-1j)` for `k=1`, `l=4`.

```
numpy.exp(-2.0*1j*np.pi*k/l)
```

I convert it to C code like below. But the output is `1.000000`.

```
#include <complex.h>
#define PI 3.1415926535897932384626434
exp(-2.0*I*PI*k/l)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You should be using `cexp()` in the C version, no?

Comment: What's `exp`? Are you using C++, or `tgmath.h`? The `exp` function in C normally doesn't take complex numbers. And how are you examining the result, anyway? Show us runnable code.

Comment: I think numpy and c will both produce the same answer once you switch `exp` to `cexp`.  The right answer is -1i.  That's what numpy is really saying when you assume that 6e-17 is really zero.

Answer (score 2):

You must use `cimag` and `creal` to print the data.

C version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <tgmath.h>


int main(){
    int k=1;
    int l=4;
    double PI = acos(-1);
    double complex z = exp(-2.0*I*PI*k/l);
    printf(" %.1f%+.1fj\n", creal(z), cimag(z));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0.0-1.0j
```

Python Version:

```
import numpy as np

k=1
l=4
z = np.exp(-2.0*1j*np.pi*k/l)
print(z)
```

Output:

```
6.12323399574e-17-1j
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the right C code to print out your answer:

```
    x = cexp(-2.0*I*PI*0.25);
    printf("%f + i%f\n", creal(x), cimag(x));
```